# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - methods

Tags: java, exception, methods, matrix

I'm new to Java. Tried to do a simple library and I've encountered a problem.

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Book.showData(Book.java:22)
>       at Book.main(Book.java:28)
>   Java Result: 1"

I know how to make this work with one method. But when I use two methods - one to read and the other one to show the data, I get an error. I think I'm not reffering to string matrix correctly but I don't really know how to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {
    int bookID;
    String bookName;
    String bookAuthor;
    int publishDate;


    public String readData(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Book's name: ");
        this.bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nAuthor's name: ");
        this.bookAuthor = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nYear of publish: ");
        this.publishDate = scanner.nextInt();
        return bookAuthor;
    }

    public void showData(){ 
        String[] names = bookAuthor.split(" ");
        System.out.println(bookName+" author is "+String.format("%s %s", names[0], names[names.length-1]));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Book().readData();
        new Book().showData();
    }
}
```

Comment: For showData() you are using new instance of Book, so all the fields are not initialized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating two instances of your `Book` object. So when you call `showData` on the second one, your Strings are not initialized (the default value for an object is `null`) and hence the NPE is thrown when you try to split on the `bookAuthor` variable.

You have to create one instance of `Book` and then perform operations on it.

```
Book b = new Book();
b.readData(); //<-- here you initialize the value fields for this instance (the instance b)
b.showData(); //<-- it's ok to use them now, they have been initialized !
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a new instance of Book 2 times in main method. As a result in the invocation of `showData()` the instance variables were not initialized, 
try

```
    Book book = new Book();
    book.readData();
    book.showData();
```

also you can move `readData()` into constructor

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {
    int bookID;
    String bookName;
    String bookAuthor;
    int publishDate;


    public Book() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Book's name: ");
        this.bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nAuthor's name: ");
        this.bookAuthor = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nYear of publish: ");
        this.publishDate = scanner.nextInt();
        return bookAuthor;
    }

    public void showData(){ 
        String[] names = bookAuthor.split(" ");
        System.out.println(bookName+" author is "+String.format("%s %s", names[0], names[names.length-1]));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Book().showData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `readData()` and `showData()` on different instances of `Book`.  You need create one instance of `Book` class and invoke your methods on that instance.

Change your main() to this :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Book book = new Book();
    book.readData();
    book.showData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are working with two different instances of `Book`. Create an instance of Book and work with that for both `readData()` and `showData()`.

```
Book book = new Book();
book.readData();
book.showData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you created two instances of the same class instead of using the same. So the `bookAuthor` variable that you initialized in `readData()` not longer exists in `showData()`.

Change your `main()` function to

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Book foo = new Book();

    foo.readData();
    foo.showData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your main() method :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Book().readData();
    new Book().showData();
}
```

In this line `new Book().readData();` you are creating new Book instance and inserting data into that instance. But when you tried yo show data you are creating another instance and trying to show data from there but it is empty because it is new `new Book().showData();`

To fix it you have to create 1 instance, insert data into it, and show data from that same instance of the class. For example like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Book book = new Book(); //create book object
    book.readData(); //insert data into it
    book.showData(); //show data from the same object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two instance of class Book.Create a single instance and call readData() and showData() functions.
Sample Code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Book myBook = new Book();

    myBook.readData();
    myBook.showData();
}
```

All other function you can keep the same.

Nullpointer is thrown because there are no values in the string for showData() when new instance is created.